# Configure Jetty Server to Not Allow TCP Fragmentation

Tags: java, jetty

I have run into an issue where the Jetty server I am integrating with is sending entire JSON's over the network and relying on [TCP fragmentation](https://www.summitir.com/2019/01/18/best-ways-to-avoid-ip-fragmentation/) when the JSON's are greater than the [MSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size). For some networks fragmentation isn't allowed and therefore communication, specifically responses from the Jetty server are being ignored because the JSON responses are being fragmented and subsequently dropped by the network.

Ultimately I would like the Jetty server to send the JSON's in pieces as to prevent TCP fragmentation over the network.

Is this possible to do with Jetty?

Comment: In what networks TCP fragmentation is not allowed?

Comment: @sbordet I am communicating over a video ip network /30. When I try to send fragmented packets over the network I get a lot of re transmissions over the network and the fragments are basically ignored when any client is connected to the network.

Comment: If you are bridging from a TCP protocol to an IP protocol, your application (the bridge) needs to do whatever is needed to respect the IP protocol requirements. This includes buffering excess content received from the TCP side, choosing the right size of bytes to send over the IP network, implement some sort of forward error correction, etc. Even if all the JSON payloads are smaller than the MSS, that would not necessarily be enough to make it work, as IP networks do have packet loss.